# 404 errors in spring mvc app running on server, but not on devbox

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a spring mvc app running on tomcat 8 on a remote CentOS 7 web server.  When I click the links to certain url patterns that call certain JSPs, it gives 404 errors. The same war file is able to run on my local CentOS 7 devbox at `localhost:8080` without throwing the 404 errors, and also runs in eclipse on my devbox using `Run As..Run on Server`, without throwing 404 errors.  **So why is the same war file throwing 404 errors on the server but not on the local devbox?**

I have confirmed that the JSP files are actually present on the server by typing `cd /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/jsp` followed by `ls -al`, and also repeating for subdirectories of that folder.

On my local devbox, all tomcat subdirectories and files are owned by root.  On the remove server, some of the folders were owned by a user who is also a member of the wheel group.  So I changed ownership of the webapps directory on the server to root, but the problem persists.  What else can I try?

Comment: Three toughts on that: 1. Your tomcat process owner needs to have access to the files. You don't mention any exception on bootstrap so I don't think that is the cause. 2. Do you have any hard coded paths in your webapp that may brake the links on the server? 3. Since it's a Spring MVC application it should not matter where the jsp files are but how your controllers are mapped. There must also appear an exception if the controllers cannot find the view (I don't think that it is just a 404 that would appear).

Comment: it seems to be a spring dependency issues, please verify all versions of spring dependency in tomcat lib folder of both devbox and server.

Comment: @CodeMed sorry, cannot access the shared stack trace (junpshare) from work.

Comment: yes, running tomcat as non-root user is preferred because of the same security issues where opening a port in root mode could be vulnerable. you can create user and group as tomcat. and chown tomcat:tomcat to the tomcat directory. but you also need to remember everytime putting webapp to the folder as same tomcat:tomcat permission. i personally recommend using tomcat as root. as i didnt see any security issue rather lot of maintainence with non-root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running tomcat as non-root user is preferred because of the same security issues where opening a port in root mode could be vulnerable. you can create user and group as tomcat. and chown tomcat:tomcat to the tomcat directory. but you also need to remember everytime putting webapp to the folder as same tomcat:tomcat permission. i personally recommend using tomcat as root. as i didnt see any security issue rather lot of maintainence with non-root.

Comment: This solved the problem.  I used `chown` to make all the tomcat subdirectories owned by the same user.